# How to Route a children file to a new page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to route my jsx file to another page without displaying on the parent page.

i have a jsx file named gpa, which i have routed to gpa from the app.jsx, so I’m i trying to route to another page from gpa.jsx which is not working

Here is the sample of the code i was using
App.jsx

```
const router = createBrowserRouter (
createRoutesFromElements (
<Route path="/" element={‹Homepage />} />
<Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
<Route path="/gpa" element={<Gpa /> }>
<Route path="/hello" element={<Hello />} />
</Route>
   
<Route path="/cgpa" element={<Cgpa />} />
));

return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
```

So i navigated from Homepage to Gpa, and from Gpa, to Hello component and i want it to display on another page not inside Gpa.jsx

Comment: Could you provide us some code? Are you using `react-router`? If you're looking for file baes routing your could checkout NextJS.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [react-router-dom](https://reactrouter.com/en/main) to create routes for you application. Assuming you have want to show a component GPA in your app.jsx when you change the url to /gpa, you can use the following code:

```
const App = () => {

const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: '/gpa',
      element: <GPA />
    }
  ])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </div>
}
```